# How to use custom audio in Toast Notification in Desktop Application correctly?

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I use custom audio in Toast Notification in Desktop Application. But I found some problems with play this audio. I have two versions of Windows:

- 1607
- 1809

In version 1607 custom audio plays perfectly. But in version 1809 custom audio file doesn't play, there is just standard sound instead my audio.

I added audio by follow code:

```cs
Audio = new ToastAudio()
{
    Src = new Uri("file:///...")
}
```

Am I missing something? Could someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: I've reached out guys from Microsoft and they told this is known issue. But there are no plans for fix this issue.

You can look at whole thread on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1593